# Move the playhead of a MovieClip and all its children

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation, vector-graphics, raster

I am converting complex animations from vector to bitmap. It is easy to convert them to bitmap when the animations are in the main timeline. However, when there are animations inside animations it all becomes very messy because I need to move all those playheads recursively...

Is there another way to achieve this? For instance, if I execute the MovieClip's `play` method, all the animations behave well but it is too slow (I can only convert one frame per each frame in the application).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'converting complex animations from vector to bitmap'? How are you doing this? Maybe some code?

Comment: It's simple, I am rasterizing an animated MovieClip into sprites using the BitmapData class. This is a common practice to improve the performance of games.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Move the playhead'? gotoAndStop()? If you are just going through each movieclip and rasterizing each and every frame I'd say the cons outweigh the pros. Oh and why do you need to rasterize the animations to bitmaps? If there are a lot of them it will probably take more processing power to do it with bitmaps than with vectors.

Comment: As I said, this is a common technique and it has two reasons: The "rasterization" is done only once, and at the beginning of the game so the framerate is constant while the user is playing. The second reason, also important, is to reduce the bandwidth required by the game. For instance, the rasterized graphics of our game occupy around 300 MB after rasterization, but the game downloads just 0,25 MB

Comment: hey miguael you r absolutely right. I too am trying to build a realtime-runtime vector movieclip to bitmapdata array rasterizer. I encounter stack overflow when trying too loop with gotoAndStop. any success in this area since this post?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should rasterize a movie clip every frame to save performance. It simply cannot speed anything up. Think about this: the Flash renderer is already turning your movie clip into a raster image so it can put it on the screen, so why do it twice?

I think what you really want is a way to **cache** the rasterizations that the renderer is already doing. If that is the case, it is very simple.

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.chacheAsBitmap = true;
```

The property is defined in [DisplayObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html). You can also do this in the Flash IDE; it is a checkbox under *Properties > Display*.

Finally, a note about when to use this: if your movie clip is changing every frame, caching it as a bitmap will not improve performance because the renderer will still have to rasterize it every frame (since its changing). **But** if your movie clip will be the same for many frames in a row, go ahead and cache it to avoid the rasterization process.

Comment: The rasterization has two reasons. The first is to ensure the framerate during the gameplay is constant. I would love to use the `cacheAsBitmap` attribute, but it does not work as good as expected (we tested that option too). The second reason is to reduce the bandwidth usage: The rasterized graphics of our game occupy around 300 MB but the game just downloads 0,25 MB of vector graphics.

Comment: We misunderstood each other. From your article, "if you do more than moving this DisplayObject on x and y, for each frame the Flash Player is updating the cached copy on memory before updating the screen." Like I said, if your movie clip is changing every frame, caching it as a bitmap will not improve performance. The article dismisses cacheAsBitmap for not being able to do what it isn't intended for. The technique you want is called blitting. I'll update my example; in the mean time, check out http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/blitting_mc.html

Comment: Another way of putting it: `cacheAsBitmap` improves performance for caching a single rasterization. You want to cache an entire animation as a sequence of bitmaps, which Flash has no native way of doing. Correct?

Comment: Yes. that's it. Also, I insist that we are doing this for the two reasons I mentioned, not just performance.